# Using StreamReader to read a .text file and split it up into arrays/classes

Tags: c#

I need to use something like StreamReader to read a .text file and spit it out into arrays that could be used for a pictureviewer and option boxes, etc.  The layout of the text file is something like:

```
PhotoURL PAGEURL SKU# Option1 Option2 Option3 .etc
```

[Edit]:
example of text file
    http://image.com/book.jpg google.com PG52389 Hardcover Ebook
    http://item.com/shirt.jpg google.com SH34920 Small Medium Large
    ExamplePhotoUrlHere google.com SE39270 Grey Black Red Blue

Not every item has every single option, so there are some blanks on certain columns.

I know I need to use streamreader to read the text file, but I'm not sure how to split it into a class with arrays and all that.

Comment: If you control the format of the file, XML serialization would be even easier. If not go with the split from the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possible starting point (just splits on spaces):

```
var linesAsArrays = File.ReadAllLines(absoluteFilePath).Split();
```

You'll need to figure out what "column" mean - because from your sample it is unclear how to separate one from another.

Note that it may be better option to find existing CSV reader instead of inventing your own.

Comment: thanks, each column is separated by a tab, or a space.  The text file has hundreds of items, and I need to display it into an app which can then grab the, lets say PhotoURL array that then create and display it in a PictureBox when I select it in a drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write a complete solution, but you could do something like this (untested)

```
char[] separators = { ' ', '\t' };

while(!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

    string[] fields = line.Split(separators, 4);

    var result = new
    {
        PhotoUrl = fields[0],
        PageUrl = fields[1],
        Sku = fields[2],
        Options = fields[3].Split(separators),
    };

    // Use result
}
```